# Recursively print next dictonaries in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, recursion, dictionary, data-structures

I'd like to print nested dictionaries in VBA. Basically I have a `Dictionary` where every key is a `String`, but each value can either be a `String` or another `Dictionary`.

Say my `Dictionary` has got the value

`{  "FOO" =>  "BAR" , "HELLO" => { "WORLD => ":)", "OTHER" => ":(" } }`

I want to display in an Excel spreadsheet:

```
FOO  |BAR  |
HELLO|WORLD|:)
HELLO|OTHER|:(
```

My issue is that I need to find a way to guess what is the type of the value under each key, so when I call `dict("HELLO")` I can either display the value if it's a string or if it's a dictionary call the same function again.

In order to do so I need to know:

- if there is a way to know what is the type of a value stored in a dictionary
- if there is a way to cast that value to a target type (string or dictionary)

So here is what I've tried

```
Function display_dictionary(dict As Scripting.Dictionary, out As Range) As Integer

  Dim vkey As Variant
  Dim key As String
  Dim row_offset As Integer
  Dim value As Object
  Dim svalue As String
  Dim dvalue As Dictionary
  Dim each_offset  As Integer

  row_offset = 0

  For Each vkey In dict.Keys()
    key = vkey
    Set value = dict(key)
    if value is String then
       svalue = ???
       out.offset(row_offset, 0).value = key
       out.offset(row_offset, 1).value = svalue
       row_offset = row_offset + 1
    else if value is Dictionary
       dvalue = ???
       each_offset = display_dictionary(dvalue, out.offset(row_offset, 1))
       For each_row = 0 To each_offset - 1
        out.offset(row_offset + each_row) = key
       Next
       row_offset = row_offset + each_offset
    End If
  Next

End
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am actually going to propose a bit different way for displaying the results. I think it's more logical but you are welcome to modify it to suit your specific needs. Just as a hint print *logical tree of nodes*, like below, and then manipulate the results if ever needed.

So the tree would look like this  for example (*Note I added one more depth level*)

[image: dictionary tree]

and the code to reproduce

```
Private i As Long
Private depth As Long

Sub Main()
Cells.ClearContents

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim subDict As New Dictionary
    Dim lvlDict As New Dictionary

    lvlDict.Add "LVL KEY", "LVL ITEM"

    subDict.Add "HELLO", ":)"
    subDict.Add "WORLD", ":("
    subDict.Add "OTHER", lvlDict

    dict.Add "FOO", "BAR"
    dict.Add "BOO", subDict

    i = 1
    depth = 0
    TraverseDictionary dict

    Columns.AutoFit

End Sub

Private Sub TraverseDictionary(d As Dictionary)

    For Each Key In d.Keys
        Range("A" & i).Offset(0, depth) = "KEY: " & Key
        If VarType(d(Key)) = 9 Then
            depth = depth + 1
            TraverseDictionary d(Key)
        Else
            Range("B" & i).Offset(0, depth) = "ITEM: " & d(Key)
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

and spreadsheet result:

[image]

---

To get the variable type or its type name you can use this:

```
Debug.Print TypeName(dict("HELLO")), VarType(dict("HELLO"))
```

Comment: I guess it's not very difficult to traverse the dictionary where items can also be dictionaries, the problem is how you are going to print it the way you want on the spreadsheet :>

Comment: +1 for the very nice work! There is a small risk, if an `Item` of a dictionary is itself an object but not a dictionary. Specifically, `VarType(d(Key)) = 9` holds true for `Objects` of any kind (I tried it with custom classes and it returned a type mismatch error). I would suggest after checking for `VarType`, also checking for dictionary specifically (eg, try to access a property and trap the error).

Comment: @Ioannis I have posted this for further discussion on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/63353/traversing-and-printing-complex-dictionary-types-scripting-dictionary-dictio)

Comment: Sorry if it is late to comment....what about traversing and printing nested Dictionaries containing Collections objects? How would one do that using your above TraverseDictionary code? Also is Typename a better indicator of type of object or is TypeOf a good one?